# Overlayer with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Can i add an overlaying "item" over the text?
Which should be centered (horizontal and vertically).

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="item-text">text</div>
  <div id="item-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/c1c7hsqj/

Comment: @Sven I think you've been in SO long enough to know you need more than this lol Come on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the current structure.

The overlay needs to be a child of the element to be overlaid...so that we can use positioning.

So.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1em;
  height:75px;
  background: plum;
}
#item-text {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: #c0ffee;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
#item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
#item-text:hover #item-overlay {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <div id="item-overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Not with the current structure." Seems to be the answer, just was not sure if it is possible to do it directly on child items. Sad ;(