# Overlay entire div to only container with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I've been trying to get a div to overlay the content in a div and only that div, not the entire page.

I've tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499519/overlayer-with-flexbox) but it actually covers the entire page. How can I get it only cover the parent?

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="document-drag-and-drop-container">
  <form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <app-textbox label="Name" formControlName="name"></app-textbox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <input type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="drag-and-drop-overlay hidden">
      <h3>Drop Document Here</h3>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

css:

```
.drag-and-drop-overlay{
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:10px 25px 25px 25px;
    border:9px solid @accent-color4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    opacity: 80%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Please, add to the question the code that you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in CSS `position: relative;` for the div you want to cover, to let your overlayer know, which area it can use. I think all you have to do here is to add:

```
.document-drag-and-drop-container {
    position: relative;
}
```